# How use strings including " character in r?

Tags: r, string, escaping, character

I have many string like below:

```
"string 1 "name" "family" "Hello""
```

I want to work with these strings like applying strsplit function and so on. But, because of being `"`, I got the error `Error: unexpected symbol`. I know I can use escape character \ in this case, but I do not want to insert any \ in my string and make it longer to process. So, is there any other solution which can be applied on this string in order to avoid such error? Thanks

Comment: Can you show your `strsplit` code.  Also, please use `dput` of the example so that we can test it

Comment: Using escape characters do not necessarily make the string longer. It's just that when R `print()`s the value, then it shows the escape characters. If you `cat()` the value, it renders the string "as is". It would be much better to show your code and your desired output to make it clear what's going on.

Comment: @akrun @MrFlick I have a text file and each line has the same structure as I shown in my question, I just have a for loop and withing loop I do `strsplit(line, "\t")`. In fact, I want to break the line as a list. I hope it is clear enough. Thanks

Comment: With that strsplit you are splitting on tabs, not quotes. It's not clear what that "unexpected symbol" error is coming from. I'm afraid this has only made things less clear.

Comment: > nmgh <- scan(file='')
1: "string 1 "name" "family" "Hello""
Error in scan(file = "") : scan() expected 'a real', got '"string', the unclosed "string starts the mayhem, and trailing double "" extends the havoc.

Comment: What do you want me to print? You haven't provided any runnable code here. I'm very unclear what's happening. You said your input is coming from a file, right? How are you reading that file? Does the data have an extra set of quotes in the file? Or is it just that when R prints those value in the console it escapes them with quotes. If i run `strsplit(line, "\t")` I don't get an "unexpected symbol" error.

Comment: As presented above, I can't get  a `line` to strsplit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagining a received text file that has the following:

```
"string 1 "name" "family" "Hello""
"string 2 "name" "family" "Bye_Bye""
"string 3 "name" "family" "But I try""
"string 4 "name" "family" "Modern Dance""
```

this might be handled via `read.csv` and `[`

```
nmgh1 <- read.csv('improbable_txt.txt', header = FALSE, sep = '"')
nmgh1 
 V1        V2   V3 V4     V5 V6           V7 V8 V9
1 NA string 1  name NA family NA        Hello NA NA
2 NA string 2  name NA family NA      Bye_Bye NA NA
3 NA string 3  name NA family NA    But I try NA NA
4 NA string 4  name NA family NA Modern Dance NA NA
```

then reduced to its essentials

```
nmgh1 <- nmgh1[, c(2,3,5,7)]
         V2   V3     V5           V7
1 string 1  name family        Hello
2 string 2  name family      Bye_Bye
3 string 3  name family    But I try
4 string 4  name family Modern Dance
```

Or so I imagine it might be. This is either a marvelously or ridiculously fragile approach dependent on the specifics of the data in the file, order of `"` & etc, but assuming the one presented line of data is consistent, it works, against all expectations. It is essentially the imbalance of `"` across each line of input ingested that allows this to work. Inconsistency of occurrance of double quotes will likely break it, hence it's fragility. A `head(dput(my_improbable_data))` as rightly requested above would be very useful in here, as in all instances, of creating both useful questions and responsive answers.